# Wso2 API MANAGER WSDL security

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have downloaded the new version of API Manager 1.0.0 GA.

I am confused about publishing the WSDLs, since that has not a related API KEY, everyone can access it.

For that reason I have tried to add access token from ESB, but that will not authenticate the API Manager's Users (like Apisubscriber) only the users inside the ESB (even if I have configured an external JDBC db for both APIManager and ESB user-mgt.xml).

So, is there a way to create an API key for WSDLs as well from the API Manager? Or How do I control the access to the published WSDLs in the API store?

Many thanks

---

**EDIT:**

From the ESB I have added security to the service by using the built-in security scenarios, in my case I have used "**UsernameToken**". This authenticates users based on roles defined in the ESB "admin/everyone..." and only accepts users defined in the ESB's user store "admin/admin" (and others you might have created).

I have ESB and AM configured to **share the same mysqlDB** for user store, but that does not work in my Security Scenario described before: if I create a user "apicreator" inside AP and I create "usertest" inside ESB, they store the users inside the same MySQL db, but under **different "tentant"**, i.e. "apicreator" is not a valid user to authenticate in my Security Scenario (UsernameToken). I hope this description helps to clarify the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

With WSO2 API Manager, you couldn't control the access to a published WSDL in API Store.Currently there's no way of creating an API key for WSDLs as well from the API Manager.But that controlling has to be done through your back-end service. How-ever when creating an API from WSO2 API Manager ,giving the Wsdl url as an input is not a required field,but an optional field.

Apart from that I'm not clear about your following phrase."For that reason I have tried to add access token from ESB, but that will not authenticate the API Manager's Users (like Apisubscriber) only the users inside the ESB".Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "add access token from ESB"?

Thanks;

/Lalaji

Comment: From the ESB I have added security to the service by using the built-in security scenarios, in my case I have used "UsernameToken". This authenticates users based on roles defined in the ESB "admin/everyone..." and only accepts users defined in the ESB's user store "admin/admin" (and others you might have created).

Comment: I have ESB and AM configured to share the same mysqlDB for user store, but that does not work in my Security Scenario described before: if I create a user "apicreator" inside AP and I create "usertest" inside ESB, they store the users inside the same MySQL db, but under different "tentant", i.e. "apicreator" is not a valid user to authenticate in my Security Scenario (UsernameToken). I hope this description helps to clarify the problem. thanks